# Motherboard booting without RAM in Dimm1

Tags: memory, motherboard, cooling

Is it possible to have a motherboard boot without placing RAM in the DIMM1 slot? Our new cooling solutions for motherboards are causing us issues where some boards that have RAM with raised heatsinks will not actually fit because the DIMM1 slot is partially blocked. Currently we mount the RAM in DIMM1 and DIMM3 because it's dual channel, are there any settings that can be changed on the BIOS to allow motherboard to boot without RAM in DIMM1 such as placing the RAM in DIMM2 and DIMM4?

Comment: Even if this was on topic for this site, you've given no information with which we could possible answer. Believe it or not, motherboards and their BIOS settings actually differ frame one make/model to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best answer is "Try it and see what happens"

Comment: Well it won't boot which is why I wanted to know if it was possible to tell it to boot from different DIMM slots.